# How to count the occurrences of random instances

Tags: java, random, count

For example I have a programming assignment that wants me to make a coin class and a driver class that randomly flips a coin 40 times and then counts at the very end how many times it ends up heads and tails.  Well I got the entire code so far it being:

```
public class driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        coin myCoin = new coin();
        System.out.println("Coin initially is " + myCoin.getSideUp());
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            myCoin.toss();
            System.out.println("Coin is now " + myCoin.getSideUp());
        }
    }
}

public class coin {
    protected String sideUp;

    public coin() {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5)
            this.sideUp = "heads";
        else
            this.sideUp = "tails";
    }

    public void toss() {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5)
            this.sideUp = "heads";
        else
            this.sideUp = "tails";
    }

    public String getSideUp() {
        return this.sideUp;
    }
}
```

That's all done, but how do I count the instances of each heads or tails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check and see if your coin is head or tail after each toss.

You could keep the counter for each status(head/tail) in an array like below:

```
Coin myCoin = new Coin();
System.out.println("Coin initially is " + myCoin.getSideUp());

int[] coinCount = new int[2];
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    myCoin.toss();
    System.out.println("Coin is now " + myCoin.getSideUp());

    if(myCoin.getSideUp().equals("heads")){
        coinCount[0]++;
    } else {
        coinCount[1]++;
    }
}

System.out.println("Heads: "+coinCount[0]);
System.out.println("Tails: "+coinCount[1]);
```

Comment: Why array? Do you expect `coinCount[0] + coinCount[1]` to be something else than 40? (Indeed sometimes coin can hang in the air... but it is not modeled in sample code :) )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Hmm.. now that I think about it, I guess you are right. Just a single `int` variable to count a status of head(or tail) would be sufficient in this case (Assuming no mid-air hang).

Comment: Woah man I'm sitting here looking at this and I wonder how I didn't realize this.  Haha I must have had such a brain fart.  Thanks man and no the coin can't get hung in the air lul this is too simple for that.

Answer (score 2):

Count them as the tosses are made instead of at the end.  If the assignment prohibits this, save the results to an array and count the results from the array at the end.